# How to detect when android 3rd party activity goes to background and comes back

Tags: android, android-activity, background, startactivityforresult

I have an app that needs to perform some action when it comes back to foreground. One other functionality is capturing image/video using

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

I'm using Application lifecycle callbacks to monitor activity activations, but when the camera activity is launched, no callback is called and the app thinks it went to background.

Is there a way to detect that the app is still in a such 3rd party activity and when this activity goes to background and back?

The recent apps list reports the app as single application, so it must know it is still in the same app.